# Sticky foooter issue with Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at the footer on [this site](http://bethhaim.spin-demo.com/).
When you scroll out or in, the footer stays at the bottom.

However, when the page loads in Chrome, I need to scroll down to see the footer regardless of how zoomed out I am. I want the footer to be visible at load instead of having to scroll down.

Basically, I need the footer to be just like it is in Firefox and IE.
Anyone know what is causing this behaviour?

Comment: The footer is at the bottom here (Chrome Canary)

Comment: It works correctly for me in Chrome.

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/p0dWJ.jpg) is how it loads for me in Chrome Dev channel. Perhaps it's only the dev channel that's messing up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its working fine in chrome (version: 17.0.963.56) of my system. Check your version or clear the history and reload again.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 19.0; That's probably the issue. thanks